# Por que minhas tabelas do asp.net mvc tem pk usuario duplicado?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Estou usando asp.net identity para autenticação e autorização

Tenho minha classe usuário:

```
public class Usuario : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin,ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{

}
public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }
public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
```

Fiz isso para poder utilizar as fk como Inteiro no asp.net mvc e não Guid como é o padrão.

Minha classe de Role

```
public class Role : IdentityRole<int, ApplicationUserRole>,IRole<int>
{

}
```

Mas em minha tabela do Banco de dados, é gerado:

```
UserId, RoleId, Usuario_Id
```

Por que isso acontece? O que há de errado?

Isso está dando problema, pois quando eu passo para adicionar uma role ao usuário:

```
await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(1, "Admin");
```

Ele preenche a coluna UserId mas a Usuario_Id não, aí se eu preencho manualmente funciona minha autorização, caso contrário não.

Comment: O nome da coluna de identificação na classe derivada é igual ao da classe herdada. Portanto, a coluna correta é `UserId`, e não `UsuarioId`.

Comment: Não @TiagoSilva, não existe a propriedade Usuario_Id em nenhuma das classes usadas do asp.net identity

Comment: Está exatamente como mostrei @TiagoSilva , nada de diferente

Comment: Só um detalhe que eu vi, se eu usar       modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().ToTable("Usuario"); Ele não duplica, mas se eu usar uma classe com EntityTypeConfiguration ele duplica o_O